# Access VBA to combine rows for a unique client id across several fields

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am currently limited to an Access DB, I am assuming I will need VBA to achieve my goal but I am unsure how to account for keeping the earliest 'visitdate' per 'BP' visit where there is dual entry (client 3)

This is an example data set

```
|--clientID--|-visitID-|--Visitdate--| BP1 | BP2 | BP3 |
|      1     |   1901  | 01/01/2015  |  0  |  1  |  0  |
|      2     |   1950  | 03/01/2015  |  1  |  0  |  0  |
|      2     |   3747  | 22/06/2015  |  0  |  0  |  1  |
|      3     |   2001  | 01/02/2015  |  1  |  0  |  0  |
|      3     |   2122  | 06/03/2015  |  0  |  1  |  0  |
|      3     |   2185  | 08/03/2015  |  1  |  0  |  1  |
```

What I would like is a single row per clientID with the earliest (min) of visit date where there are two BPx entries (client 3).

```
|--clientID--|-BP1-|-BP2-|-BP3-|-BP1Visitdate-|-BP2Visitdate-|-BP3Visitdate-|
|      1     |  0  |  1  |  0  |   No BP1     |  01/01/2015  |   No BP3     |
|      2     |  1  |  0  |  1  | 03/01/2015   |   N0 BP2     |  22/06/2015  |
|      3     |  1  |  1  |  1  | 01/02/2015   |  06/03/2015  |  08/03/2015  |
```

Answer (score 0):

For Each BP column you have, you could have a query to get the MIN date per client, then join them all in another query or the distinct clients